# Inserting a series of equally-spaced dots in math-mode

Tags: vertical-alignment, ellipsis

1. A series of equally-spaced dots are required to complete the set up.
2. A slight adjustment of the vertical alignment is required.

[image]

**The above set up must appear as something like this:-**

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
using the detached coefficients, we have the scheme\\\\
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r @{} >{{}}r *{20}{ @{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{} } }
& 1 & + & _nC_{1} & + & _nC_{2} & + & _nC_{3} & + & \dotsb  & + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\times \\
& 1 & + &  1      & \\
\midrule
& 1 &   &         & + & _nC_{1} &   &         & + & _nC_{2} &   &   &   &   &   &   &         & + & _nC_{n} \\
&   &   &         & + &  1      &   &         & + & _nC_{1} &   &   &   &   &   &   &      & + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\midrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\hdotsfor` from `amsmath` (the argument indicates the number of columns to be spanned):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
using the detached coefficients, we have the scheme\\\\
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r @{} >{{}}r *{20}{ @{}>{{}}r<{{}}@{} } }
& 1 & + & _nC_{1} & + & _nC_{2} & + & _nC_{3} & + & \dotsb  & + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\times \\
& 1 & + &  1      & \\
\midrule
& 1 &   &         & + & _nC_{1} & \hdotsfor{2}          & + & _nC_{2} &   \hdotsfor{3}           + & _nC_{n} \\
&   &   &         & + &  1  & \hdotsfor{2}         & + & _nC_{1} &  \hdotsfor{3}       + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\midrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `l` (left) aligned columns strating from the second one:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
using the detached coefficients, we have the scheme\\\\
\noindent
$\begin{array}{@{} >{{}}r @{} >{{}}r *{20}{ @{}>{{}}l<{{}}@{} } }
& 1 & + & _nC_{1} & + & _nC_{2} & + & _nC_{3} & + & \dotsb  & + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\times \\
& 1 & + &  1      & \\
\midrule
& 1 &   &         & + & _nC_{1} & \hdotsfor{2}          & + & _nC_{2} &   \hdotsfor{3}           + & _nC_{n} \\
&   &   &         & + &  1  & \hdotsfor{2}         & + & _nC_{1} &  \hdotsfor{3}       + & _nC_{n-1} & + & _nC_{n} \\
\midrule
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the improvement! I really appreciate it. 
Would it be difficult for you to align the set up as in the `second` figure? Example:- Of the second row, `+` and `1` are quite distant apart.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa just change all the `r` but the first one to `l`. I am talking about your `\begin{array}{...}` definition

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Are you suggesting me to replace the first `r` by 1?

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa No, not the first one. The other one(s), where left alignment is desired.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The space reduces, and it partially works; but an error occurred.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina To be honest, without the correct alignment I cannot write the final result by adding them to-gether. I tried different ways, but neither worked.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa please decsribe in detail the desired alignment using as reference the image in my answer.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa Please see my updated answer with left alignment. Is it something like that what you want?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just want the same alignment as appeared in the `second figure`.  Of the second line, the second `1` has shifted towards right-side. I want it under the subscript `n`; just as in the second figure.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You did it perfectly. BUT, I want it the other way. `1` must stand under the subscript `n`.  The opposite of what you did. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21645/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-nisal-kevin-kotinkaduwa).

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa Please follow the link in the comment right above, so we can discuss in a chat room the issue.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am extremely sorry for making you wait. They ask for 20 reputation to chat.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa No problem. That's odd. You already have more than 20 rep. Well, let's then discuss hree.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa I am confused; you said "1 must stand under the subscript n" and that's what my second code does, isn't it? I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You did it! You did what I exactly wanted.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you very much for taking time to solve my problem. I have been working on a project which is very important. So your help is kept in high regard.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.