# Aligned equations and dotted line

Tags: align, alignat

I'm trying to align equations with dotted line between them, but the `{aligned}` enviroment doesn't work. Does anybody have any idea how to do this?

```
\begin{aligned}
(a_{11}-t)x_1 + a_{12}x_2+\dots+&& a_{1n}x_b=0,& \\
&&\parbox[t]{90pt}{\dotfill}& \\
a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2}x_2+\dots+&&(a_{nn}-t)x_n=0.&
\end{aligned}
```

[image]

Comment: Which parts of the equations do you want to align?

Comment: equations looks ok, it's about dotted line - should be aligned to right side and has length like the lower equation

Comment: Related: [Inserting a series of equally-spaced dots in math-mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231344/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\hdotsfor{<num>}` to spread dots across `<num>` columns in an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% Remove separation between array columns
  \begin{array}{rr}
    (a_{11} - t) x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \dots + {}&       a_{1n} x_b = 0, \\
    \hdotsfor{2} \\
           a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2} x_2 + \dots + {}& (a_{nn} - t) x_n = 0.
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% Remove separation between array columns
  \begin{array}{rrrrl}
    (a_{11} - t) x_1 + {}& a_{12} x_2 + &{} \dots + {}&       a_{1n} x_b = {}& 0, \\
    \hdotsfor{5} \\
           a_{n1}x_1 + {}& a_{n2} x_2 + &{} \dots + {}& (a_{nn} - t) x_n = {}& 0.
  \end{array}
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The first example uses only two columns - one for the LHS and the other for the RHS of the equations. The second example adds more alignment points to ensure the content has proper horizontal alignment around each operator/relation.

If you truly want the horizontal line to be the width of the lower equation, then you can use

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

%...

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% Remove separation between array columns
  \begin{array}{rr}
    \phantom{a_{n1}}\mathllap{(a_{11} - t)} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \dots + {}&       a_{1n} x_b = 0, \\
    \hdotsfor{2} \\
           a_{n1}x_1 + a_{n2} x_2 + \dots + {}& (a_{nn} - t) x_n = 0.
  \end{array}
\]
```

[image]